# Strange issue with global variables & for loops

Tags: python

I was fooling around today and decided to create a program that prints out a beach, unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I want it to. Here is the source code for it:

```
def beach1():
    for i in range(7):
        global beach, water, land
      (beach, water, land) = (5, 0 + 5, 35 - 5)
        print(''.join(['o' for i in range(land)])+''.join(['*' for i in  range(beach)])+''.join(['~' for i in range(water)]))
beach1()
```

Here is the current output:

```
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
```

And here is what I **want** it to output:

```
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
ooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
oooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The reason I expect the output to change is because of the three variables, `land`, `beach`, and `water`. Since these variables are global, they retain their value, so every time the `for` loop repeats, `land`'s value will go down by 5. Therefore the land section of the output will be printed 5 less times every time the loop repeats. Vice versa for the water section of the output. When I came up with the idea in my head, it seemed like it would work, but now it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? All help is appreciated, thanks! Also, if you can come up with a better title, feel free to, I certainly can't.

Comment: Please walk us through *why* you expect the output to change, I'm pretty sure in doing so you'll be able to figure out why this happens yourself.

Comment: FYI, `'o'*land` is a much shorter method for generating a string of `o`s.

Comment: Hint: You aren't changing the values of any of your variables.

Comment: Is your issue that you are using 'I' as the index for both your inner and outer loops. Also when you calculate beach, water and land they are exactly the same value each round your outer loop - as your calculation doesn't include 'I' in any way

Comment: @chepner You're right, and it probably is more efficient. I should fix that. It also doesn't exceed 80 characters in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the size of your 3 areas with this:

```
(beach, water, land) = (5, 0 + 5, 35 - 5)
```

Which is a constant value, so it won't change during the `for` loop!

Juste make the values depend on `i`, like this:

```
for i in range(8):
    (beach, water, land) = (5, 5+5*i, 35-5*i)
```

Moreover, you are using the same variable, `i`, for your main loop and your inner loops on line  5. You have to rename one of them!

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how much I failed not realizing that...       ****facepalm****

Comment: Well, if you don't need to use `beach`, `water` and `land` outside the main `for` loop, you don't need to set them as `global`.

Comment: How could I make it so the land section prints out a random character? I already tried to use `random.randint()` and `random.choice()`, but they both threw errors. How could I do this?

Comment: You should start another question to try to get an answer to this new one.

Comment: Never mind, I accidentally added an extra `()` to `random.choice()`.

Answer (score 2):

you could also make your prints simpler…

```
>>> for i in range(1,8):
...     print('%s%s%s' % ('o'*5*(7-i), '*'*5, '~'*5*(i)))
... 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~
ooooooooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~
oooooooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ooooooooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
oooooooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ooooo*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```